# Why is the ps format option '%a' truncated?

Tags: bash, ps

I'm trying to read the output of `ps` using a custom format specified with `-o`. Because I want to specify a custom separator I'm using AIX format descriptors (e.g. `%p` for pid, `%a` for args etc), but the same issue is seen when using the normal formatting codes.

When I specify `%a` at the end of this format string, all works as expected:

```bsh
$ echo 'while true; do sleep 1; done' > really-really-really-long-filename 

$ bash really-really-really-long-filename &
[1] 31181

$ ps -p 31181 -o '%p|%a'

  PID|COMMAND
31181|bash really-really-really-long-filename
```

However if `%a` is not the last field, I get this:

```bsh
$ ps -p 31181 -o '%a|%p'

COMMAND                    |  PID
bash really-really-really-l|31181
```

This doesn't seem to be related to any screen-width modifiers. Is there something else at play here?

(GNU bash 4.1.5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but you could mix and match formats just so you can use width control for selected fields. E.g.

```
[me@home]$ ps -p 780 -o "%a|%p"
COMMAND                    |  PID
dbus-daemon --system --fork|  780

[me@home]$ ps -p 780 -o args:50 -o "|%p"
COMMAND                                           |  PID
dbus-daemon --system --fork --activation=upstart  |  780
```

As for why the truncation happens, my *guess* is there's a hardcoded width that is used for each field (unless a width is specified by the user) when it is not the last field. This saves the program having to first buffer the output to determine the maximum column width before printing.

In the case of `args` the default hardcoded width seems to be `27` (see [this implementation of `ps`](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/v3.3.7/ps/output.c#L1376)).

I should mention that this is just a purely speculation on my part and may not necessarily be the case.

Comment: @cbuckley The values I see in `/proc/$PID/status` do not seem to correspond to the output I'm seeing in `ps`. I came to the above conclusion because the truncation length did correspond to the table in the source code (27 for args, 5 for pid, etc).